# Carving out a /28 network and still maintaining access to parent /24 network

Tags: routing, subnet, design

In the diagram below, I'd like to carve out a /28 network from 192.168.0.0/24 and move it to another geographical location and still maintain access in and out of the original /24 network.

Essentially there would be a dead address space between 192.168.0.96 and 192.168.0.111 as that would be a new network that's connected to the 192.168.10.1 gateway router. I'm open to any suggestion on how to accomplish this, and if NAT would potentially break certain protocols, then I'd like to stay away from that.

[image]

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the so-call duplicate, there is no mention of NAT in the question and no need for NAT to solve this problem.

Comment: @PeterGreen, the original question (deleted, then asked here), says, "_Would it be possible to carve out a small subnet, say 192.168.0.96/28 on the 192.168.10.0/24 network and then use NAT on the routers to point clients to the server(s)?_" The request in both questions was to add the server, at its old address to a different network, but a device connected to a network must have an address in the network to which it is connected.

Comment: *Is this something that can be accomplished* - there are many things that *can* be done, and in this case it is possible. However, the more important question is often *should this be done?* In this case, the answer is no. Any way that enables this type of configuration is asking for larger problems to affect the entire network.

Comment: @PeterGreen I don't necessarily need to use NAT, and I only suggested NAT as I didn't know any other way of solving this issue. I'm certainly open to any suggestions, and if NAT would potentially break other protocols then I'd have to use something else anyway. You mention that NAT isn't needed to solve this issue, how can I solve it without using NAT?

Comment: Using the method that he explained requires a custom routing configuration be put on every host (off-topic here) on the network and the use of secondary addressing on the new network, along with routing changes to the routers. This is probably something you do not want to attempt yourself because you had to ask the question. It will also mean that the custom host configuration will need to be configured on every host later added to the network. You should heed the last sentence is YLearn's comment.

Comment: Adding a static route on the hosts was only one of the two possible options I gave.

Comment: Are you able to change the server’s subnet mask and gateway?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can be acomplished.

Most of the setup will be the same as for any other new network. You would add the new network as a second network on the router interface facing the 192.168.10.0 network, then make sure all your routers have routes to it (either by static routes or by some routing protocol). Routers use a longest prefix match, so routers with a route to the new network will route packets to it in preference to the old one.

However there is one detail that needs to be attended to. When hosts on the old 192.168.0.0/24 network try to send packets to hosts on 192.168.0.96/28 they will by default arp for the destination address rather than the gateway address. In a default configuration this will result in a failure to deliver the packets.

To resolve this we have two options.

1. Add a static route on the hosts in the old network to send the traffic to the router.
2. Configure the router facing the 192.168.0.0/24 network to "proxy arp" for the IPs in question.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have overlapping networks. Network addressing for a network must be contiguous. If you use part of a parent network, then the parent network no longer exists, only the subnets you have created from the parent network.

If you try to use part of a network somewhere else as you have described, hosts on the original network cannot access the part you have moved. The way a host uses a gateway (router) is that all packets are encapsulated frames and delivered on the local network. A host will mask the destination address on a packet with its mask and compare that to its own masked address to see if they are on the same network. If they are, it will use ARP to get the destination MAC address, but the host on the remote network will never respond, so the packet will be dropped. If the destination IP address is on a different network, the host will use ARP to get the gateway address and encapsulate the packet in a frame destined for its gateway. The router will get it and look up how to reach the destination network. If the address is in the source network, which will be the network from where the packet originated.

Also, devices addressed in one network (`192.168.0.96/28`) cannot connect to a different network (`192.168.10.0/24`) unless the addresses are changed to the new network. For example, when a device addressed in the old network is attached to the new network, it cannot communicate with other devices on the new network, including the gateway of the new network, because it will need to send traffic to its configured gateway, which must be in the same network (old) as it, but the gateway is in the new network. It would require a gateway to reach the gateway, and you cannot do that.

You would need to create a completely separate new network, not add to an existing network.

What you propose cannot work.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94363/discussion-on-answer-by-ron-maupin-carving-out-a-28-network-and-still-maintaini).

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do has serious implications. As Peter's pointed out it's possible with some workarounds but those are not easy to handle. Overlapping networks and proxy ARP become major pains over time as Ron's pointed out.

I'd propose a more sensible approach: use another subnet. Private IP addresses are free to use and you can easily just define a new subnet, set up the routes and you're done. If you *really* need the /28 subnet's hosts to map into the /24 net you could use destination NAT. NAT is generally ugly but not as bad as fiddling with proxy ARP and split route metrics.

[**edit**] Since all else fails, you should consider using virtual addresses instead of the unchangeable, local addresses. So, instead of other hosts connecting to 192.168.0.96 through 192.168.0.111 directly, they'd connect to e.g. 192.168.255.96 through 192.168.255.111.

A NAT router in front of the destination subnet takes care of translating those virtual addresses to the actual device addresses. That way you could also move those devices around at will, just changing their virtual address on the NAT router to something you can route.

Comment: What if you can't change the IP address on the host that needs to be moved? That's the main issue I'm facing, and I've exhausted all possibilities in trying to change those addresses to something else. I need to physically move a device (server) from one location to the other while keeping the existing IP address.

Comment: @Cragmuer: Why _exactly_  "can't change the IP address" ? (see answer below...)

Comment: @Cragmuer Then you should consider moving the IP subnet with it and renumber the remaining hosts.

Comment: Unfortunately the software running on the device is so old and horribly designed that the IP address cannot be changed without reinstalling it. It can't be reinstalled because the vendor no longer supports that software. It cannot be upgraded as there is no upgraded version to move to. I've really exhausted any and all possibilities trying to change the IP address in a test environment and nothing works.

Comment: @Cragmuer I mean, *move the entire IP subnet along with the device.* Then, change the old subnet to another network address.

Comment: @Zac67 Unfortunately that's not possible either. There's a portion of the building that houses that network that's being demolished, and that's where this device lives. If I could change all the other devices I'd certainly do that, but there's more devices on that network than just this one that have hard-coded IP addresses.

Comment: @Cragmuer I've added another proposal to my answer that should work in any case and is most probably the least ugly approach.

Answer (score 1):

> without changing the IP address

Why *exactly* ?

If the reason  happens to be because of some (legacy?) software package that has its licensing bound to an IP address (and/or MAC address?), things might be quite simple.

**EDIT:** ... and probably on the edge of being off-topic for Network Engineering, because more related to host and client configuration than anything else.

Try this:

- connect the server to its new home network and give it suitable IP
  address, mask and gateway settings.
- Adjust DNS entries and/or client side configurations as needed, pointing to the server's new IP address.

Then, try to fool the software/licensing into believing the server still has its old IP address:

- add a dummy NIC to that server, and connect it to some stub vlan of the new site (or plug a loop cable into it), anything to make the NIC it appear as "up". The subnet mask might even be 255.255.255.255, if the operating system supports it.
- configure that dummy NIC it with the old/licensed IP address and the longest subnet mask possible/supported by the OS.
- Make sure that the original network has no active IP addresses in the IP range covered by the dummy NIC's IP and subnet mask.

(If there's even a MAC/IP combination involved with licensing, then just keep using the current NIC as the dummy one in the stub network, and add a new NIC for the "proper" network).

If however, the unchangeability is because client software cannot be reconfigured (in extenso: hard-coded IP addresses), then that won't help, I'm afraid, and you'll probably have to resort to the poison cabinet of networking, where bottles labelled "static routes on client systems" and "proxy arp" (see Peter Green's answer) are kept, and where you'll also find the jar with the "obscure NAT" pills.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marc, and yes, unfortunately it's a case of hard-coded IP addresses.

Comment: ... there should be implicit retro-active contractual penalties for any developer or company, ranging from "large percentage of annual renveue" fines to things close to violating the geneva conventions, for delivering a product that is fundamentally broken in such a way... *sigh*.